# ajax call to send access token fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello I'm trying to allow login in my app through facebook, and than I want to get some info with the access token I'm getting.

I'm trying to pass the access token from facebook js sdk to a webmethod on the server for me to use it later, but the call is failing.

**here's my aspx:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login Authentication Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>


    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    // Init the SDK upon load
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '474928559284763', // App ID
            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook

                var dataString = JSON.stringify({ access_T: response.authResponse.accessToken });
                alert(dataString);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    url: "Default2.aspx/save_access_token",
                    data: dataString,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {


                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(result.d);
                    }
                });


                FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                    if (me.name) {
                        document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;


                    }
                })
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
            }
            //here

            //
            $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () { FB.logout(function () { window.location.reload(); }); });
        });
    }
</script>
<h1>
Facebook Login Authentication Example</h1>
<div id="auth-status">
<div id="auth-loggedout">

<div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" scope="email,user_checkins">Login with Facebook</div>
</div>
<div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>(<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**here's my webmethod:**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void save_access_token(string access_T)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["a_t"] = access_T;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I checked to see what is written on the post and here it is:

[image]

Comment: "the call is failing"...with error? any other info to provide here?

Comment: It just alerts the undefined result, which means it enters the error function

Comment: If you're doing this locally, can you debug? And if not, can you use fiddler or the developer tools in your browser to determine what is being posted?

Comment: I debugged with chrome, but it just gets to the ajax call and throws the error. how do I check what is being posted?

Comment: The network tab along the top of the chrome developer tools should show you any gets or posts. Click on the one that fails and it should show you the details of that call (headers, preview, response, etc).

Comment: I added a screenshot of the post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43682/discussion-between-ethorn10-and-dvirski)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. something with the web form was not right, when I started a new one it worked.